# anythingslider and cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Let's say that i wish to dynamically generate a [anythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) jquery script from a cakephp view. Even if CakePHP seems to have some useful functions isn JS helper good to use in this task, I can't figure it how to do it. Do I have to rewrite the jquery script or what cakephp method to use?

```
$(function() {
    $('#slider1').anythingSlider({
        buildArrows : false,
        }); 
});
```

Comment: I need it to do the same thing, but from all the cakephp js methods, only the event() seems to fit to my needs. The problem is that this script can't be "translated" to be used by the event function

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother "translating it to CakePHP". Best case you'll get the exact same Javascript back out of it, worst case you'll waste hours trying to figure out why you don't. IMHO if you're comfortable writing Javascript yourself, just do it. :)

Comment: the thing is that i need to send the params dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "the thing is that i need to send the params dynamically"

Many ways to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
    $('<?php echo $variable; ?>').anythingSlider({
        buildArrows : false
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Or:

```
$this->Html->scriptBlock('$(function() { $("' . $variable . '").anythingSlider({ buildArrows : false }); });', array('inline' => false));
```

Or:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var foo = '<?php echo $variable; ?>';
</script>


$(function() {
    $(foo).anythingSlider({
        buildArrows : false
    }); 
});
```